# Al recargar la web se actualiza el estado del redux

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

estoy realizando un login para una web y al iniciar sesión se guarda el token en el localstorage y se me guarda la sesion pero al actualizar la pagina el isLogged que tengo en el redux me cambia a falso y el token queda en el localstorage pero el botón se me cambia como si no estuviera logeado

necesitaría aprender algo como verificar si el token esta todavía al recargar la pagina y meterle nuevamente el user al redux pero nose como hacerlo

**Reducer**

```
const auth = (auth = {
    data: {},
    isLogged: false,
    isFetching: false,
  }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_AUTH':
    case 'REQUEST_AUTH':
      return {
        data: {},
        isLogged: false,
        isFetching: false,
      }
    case 'RECEIVE_AUTH':
      return {
        data: action.user,
        isLogged: true,
        isFetching: false,
      }
    default:
      return auth
  }
}
```

**Botones de inicio de sesión**

```
        <div>
        {
          props.auth.isLogged ?
          <Button
            className='pt-sm-3 pt-lg-3 pt-xl-3 me-3 text-secondary'
            onClick={_handleLogout}
            type='submit'
            variant='light'
          >
            <BiUser size='1.5em'/>
            <p className='d-none d-sm-block'>Mi Cuenta</p>
          </Button>
          :
          <Button
            className='pt-sm-3 pt-lg-4 pt-xl-4 me-3 m-3 text-secondary'
            href='/login'
            type='submit'
            variant='light'
          >
            <BiLogIn size='1.5em'/>
            <p className='d-none d-sm-block'>Ingresar</p>
          </Button>
        }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar definir un token en el `localStorage`, y utilizar un `useEffect` que siempre verifique ese token. Si existe, esteblece nuevamente `isLogged` en true a través de una acción.